# Is it possible to create a new instance of base class based on a given identifier and vice versa in C++

Tags: c++

I have a base class and multiple subclasses extending it. My goal is to create a new instance of one of the subclasses based on the identifier and vice versa using C++. I have used a switch-case statement like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<base> create(int id)
{
    std::shared_ptr<base> p;
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        p = std::make_shared<derived1>();
        break;

    case 1:
        p = std::make_shared<derived2>();
        break;

    default:
        throw;
    }

    return p;
}
```

but I would like a more elegant method that works also vice versa.
Here is a working implementation of my goal coded in Java:

```
static BiMap<Integer, Class<? extends Base>> map = HashBiMap.create();

static {
    map.put(0, Derived1.class);
    map.put(1, Derived2.class);
}

static Base createInstance(int id) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    return map.get(id).newInstance();
}

static int getId(Base instance) {
    return map.inverse().get(instance.getClass());
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe something like std::map<int,std::shared_ptr<base> (*)()>? A map with an integer as key and a function pointer returning a shared_pointer.

Comment: Do-able, but not particularly convenient. C++'s lack of reflection gets you.

Comment: See also Factory Design Pattern.

Comment: @user4581301 [You don't really need reflection](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c51604dd39e79470)

Comment: @MooingDuck [Just figured that out myself.](https://godbolt.org/z/fTcs1q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not have metaclasses, like Java does.  So the closest C++ equivalent of that Java code would look something like this:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    ...
    virtual int getId() const = 0;
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
    ...
    int getId() const override { return 0; }
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
public:
    ...
    int getId() const override { return 1; }
};

...

using createFunc = std::shared_ptr<Base>(*)();

static std::map<int, createFunc> myMap
{
    {0, []() -> std::shared_ptr<Base> { return std::make_shared<Derived1>(); }},
    {1, []() -> std::shared_ptr<Base> { return std::make_shared<Derived2>(); }}
    ...
};

static std::shared_ptr<Base> createInstance(int id)
{
    auto iter = myMap.find(id);
    if (iter == myMap.end())
        throw ...;
    return iter->second();
}

static int getId(Base* instance)
// or: static int getId(std::shared_ptr<Base> &instance)
{
    return instance->getId();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/GTCgsZ)

Comment: An array would be drastically faster than a `std::map` for this case.

Comment: @MooingDuck In this particular example, yes. But who is to say that maybe in the future the OP will want to register the classes dynamically instead, such as my moving the implementations into separate units.  You can't use a fixed array for that (well, you can, but you would have to limit the max number of classes that can be registered)

Answer (score -2):

I'd have a virtual function called something like `_getId()`. Then you could have each derived class return its unique identifier:

```
class base {
    ...
    virtual int _getId() = 0;
};

class derived1: public base {
    ...
    int _getId() { return 1; }
};

...
```

So your static base `getId()` could look like:

```
static int getId(base *instance) {
    return instance->_getId();
}
```

Comment: This only addresses half of the user's question.  It doesn't address how to implement `create(id)` at all.

Comment: @Remy it looks like OP already has a working `create()` method, no?

Comment: @scohe001 they do, but they dislike it and want to replace it with a map.